# Meeting invites not sent to Contacts in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, exchange-server, microsoft-dynamics, server-side-sync

I'm having an issue, I have an On-Premise CRM Dynamics environment with Server Side synchronization, the sync works fine.
When creating appointments the System Users receive a meeting invite, but this is not sent to contacts in the system (even though some of them are emails from the same AD).

Is there an error log I can check, or some extra configuration needed in exchange server for it to work?

P.S. I'm attaching the current configuration.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When using server side synchronization, the account used as part of the authentication setup must have elevated permissions to send email on behalf of others or you need to modify the user's settings to allow others to send emails on their behalf, this could be what is causing the issue, also could you open up the emails that were not sent, they should also have an error message describing why the sending the email failed.

Comment: Hello @dotnetnetdot thanks for the information, I added the user permission to send mails on behalf of others and I allowed other users to send messages on my behalf, but still contacts are not getting meeting invites (I tested with my user). Where can I check the not sent emails emails? They aren't visible by advanced find.

Comment: Don't they show up under "Email" entity results? How are the emails "sent" ? a workflow?

Comment: By emails I mean Meeting invitation (those that are sent when you create an appointment), it works fine for users, but contacts do not receive and invitation. Isn't that something done naturally by the system?

Comment: Ok, maybe I misread the entire question then, No, when a user creates an appointment no email is sent out to external contacts (recipients).